# Software center becoming fully transperent

Tags: software-center

After updating from 18.04 to 20.04 my software center become fully transparent.

[image]

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is late 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: This doesn't appear to happen with all externally installed themes - problem should possibly be with the theme becoming incompatible with 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the theme. Not all themes have this transparency issue.

You can try installing a different theme from here: https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/135/ord/latest/ (Many of these may have the same issue)

or

You can create your own theme using Oomox: https://www.ostechnix.com/oomox-customize-and-create-your-own-gtk2-gtk3-themes/

(Here is the link to the Oomox theme I created to get rid of this issue: [Coffeetose](https://aakashsinghbais.github.io/coffeetose/), it may not be the best one though!)

...as a last resort, you can definitely change back to one of the default themes...!

I hope this will solve your problem for now.

Answer (score 1):

Change the theme of the application window back to Yaru (bug). For some reason there an issue applying themes the certain windows.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer to that.

When you install a custom theme which is under `root` or `sudo` that are at `/usr/local/themes` should be moved to `/home/$USER/.themes` and When you apply your custom theme, All the apps will have your custom theme applied except the software center which will be on default white `Yaru` theme.

And when the developers update their themes compatible to Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu software center will also work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue with every theme other than Yaro! On Ubuntu 20.04 all you have to do is install flatpak and the transparency will go away after a reboot. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/02/how-to-install-flatpak-on-ubuntu-flathub