# Ubuntu 20.04 gnome themes break the Ubuntu Software app

Tags: gnome, themes

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. I installed `gnome-tweaks` and `chrome-gnome-shell` to enable themes.

My theme works on all apps except the Ubuntu Software app; it's a really minor, annoying thing. I've tried with both Ant themes, and the screenshot is using Adapta.

[image: Screenshot of Ubuntu Software app while using the theme]

Any way I can fix it?

Comment: Hey genfy! Try opening Ubuntu Software app from terminal and check if there's something mentioned in terminal. To open Ubuntu Software app through terminal, paste this: `snap-store` and press Enter. If something is mentioned in terminal, copy it and paste it in the question.

Comment: There's no error unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem: [Ubuntu 20.04 GNOME Flashback - Snap Shop transparent on non-default themes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245851/ubuntu-20-04-gnome-flashback-snap-shop-transparent-on-non-default-themes)

I solved it by installing the `overlay` snap application and writing a script run every time the system starts up that remounts the GNOME Core snap read/write and adds my theme files to it. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -d /snap/overlay ]; then
  exit 1
fi

GNOMEDIR=`echo /snap/gnome-3-*`

if [ -z "$GNOMEDIR" ]; then
  exit 1
fi

for ff in $GNOMEDIR; do

  GNOMEVER=`readlink $ff/current`

  if [ -z "$GNOMEVER" ]; then
    exit 1
  fi

  /snap/overlay/current/overlay $ff/$GNOMEVER
  cp -rp "/usr/share/themes/My Theme" $ff/$GNOMEVER/usr/share/themes
  rm "$ff/$GNOMEVER/usr/share/themes/My Theme/gtk-3.0/assets"
  ln -s /snap/gtk-common-themes/current/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets "$ff/$GNOMEVER/usr/share/themes/My Theme/gtk-3.0"

done
```

My theme is installed as `/usr/share/themes/My Theme`. The last `rm` and `ln -s` commands in the script modify the symbolic link that originally points from `My Theme` directory into Ambiance theme directory (as my theme is based on the Radiance theme which uses the same icons etc. as Ambiance), so that it points to correct place within GNOME snap directory.

If your theme does not have such links, just remove those two commands.

To make this script run every time the system starts up, I added the following file to `/etc/cron.d` directory:

```
@reboot root /usr/local/sbin/overlay-mytheme
```

where `/usr/local/sbin/overlay-mytheme` is the above script of course :)