# Ubuntu 20.04, Snap Store does not start

Tags: 20.04, snap-store

Suddenly, Snap Store does not start. When started from the terminal, it displays the message:

```
/snap/snap-store/518/usr/bin/snap-store: symbol lookup error: /snap/snap-store/518/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: atk_plug_set_child
```

Did some recent update maybe break something?
How to fix it?

(I can use GNOME Software as workaround, that works correctly)

Comment: I already found an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344650/cant-open-snap-store). So the question may be closed.

Comment: Good. Don't use it. Snap does not repect your theme (besides the default ones) and often leads to problems. Try to use deb packages from the repository, which the Gnome Software Center supplies.

Comment: @kanehekili I found a way for snaps to use my theme: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285930/ubuntu-20-04-gnome-themes-break-the-ubuntu-software-app/1286550#1286550

Comment: Thanks, but no thanks. Snap will not ever stay on my devices. First step towards windows...

Comment: @N0rbert as I wrote above, I already found that answer. I even commented there that the old version of Snap Store you suggest to install is little useful, there's very little software available, you cannot select channels to install etc.

Comment: Then remove Snapd and use Flatpak instead. Or use Plasma Discover with [both plugins](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=plasma%20discover).

Comment: @N0rbert You misunderstood me. I don't want to get rid of Snap Store. The current version of Snap Store, that stopped working, was good. Only the old one from the "candidate" channel, that you suggest as workaround, is very outdated, so it's bascially not usable as workaround. Seems there's no other option as wait for the fix...